# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException How to initialise SessionFactory bean?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

I have a question. I tried to run my web application using Spring and Hibernate/ I have a strange error. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. Stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:837)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
```

I do not know why, because in my servlet-context.xml I declared SessionFacory bean:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.service.impl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao.impl.hibernate" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.entity" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="userService" class="com.example.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDAO" class="com.example.dao.impl.hibernate.HibernateUserDAO" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/userdb" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pswd" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.entity.User</value>
            <value>com.example.entity.Role</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            hibernate.show_sql=true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Also, I annotated all DAO implementations and service implementations.
Any ideas?

**Added**

This is part of my code:

```
@Repository
public class HibernateUserDAO implements UserDAO {
   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
   ...
}
```

And Service class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

@Override
@Transactional
public void create(User user) throws SQLException {
    userDAO.create(user);
}
```

full stacktrace:

```
Sep 20, 2013 10:54:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class   
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name         'hibernateUserDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.example.dao.impl.hibernate.HibernateUserDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire               field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory    com.example.dao.impl.hibernate.HibernateUserDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:837)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
... 25 more
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Don't look like Hibernate is on your class path. Make sure that Hibernate and all its dependencies are in your `lib` folder.

Comment: I'm sure that all required jars in my classpath and in lib folder

Comment: In short, your beans are in the wrong location, next to that you have a lot of duplication going on. For the longer version, see my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would start with cleaning your configuration

This

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

Includes all this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.service.impl" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao.impl.hibernate" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.entity" />
```

You are using component scanning so no need to explicitly define all the beans (it would make component scanning pretty useless if that was still needed).

Next these 2 beans

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
```

Are already implied by `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Basically leaves you with this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/userdb" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pswd" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.entity.User</value>
            <value>com.example.entity.Role</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            hibernate.show_sql=true
        </value>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Not that it will solve your problem because the error is not due to the fact that the configuration is incomplete, but the configuration is in the wrong place. The `datasource`, `sessionFactory`, `transactionManager` and `<tx:annotation-driven .. />` must be moved to the `applicationContext.xml`. Nex to that your applicationContext.xml should also include a component-scan which scans for everything **but** controllers.

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" value="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan">
```

Change the `<component-scan .. />` in your servlet-context.xml to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" value="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan">
```

This to prevent duplicate instantiation of your `@Service` and `@Repository` beans. Which is what is happening now (both your `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` are loading and creating the same beans, which would lead you to other nice exceptions and next to that duplication of memory as you have 2 instances of each bean in memory).

Comment: Why I need 2 xml files? I saw many examples with 1 xml. And so, I can't understand what should be in this two files separately?

Comment: Judging from yuo stacktrace you have a `ContextLoaderListener` (and you are using Spring Security) and a `DispatcherServlet`. They should **NOT** both load the same xml file. Post your web.xml.

Comment: You already have multiple files so I don't see the problem. Basically where I mention applicationContext.xml you should read root-context.xml and servlet-context.xml == dispatcher-servlet.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you use @Autowired you don't need to declare like a property at the context. But it must be at the context--->NoSuchBeanDefinition--> don't find it.

```
<bean id="userService" class="com.example.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" /> 
</bean>
```

try to remove userDAO from property context.--if you autowired it, you don't need it at context.

but the problem seems to be at this bean:

```
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.example.dao.impl.hibernate.HibernateUserDAO" />
```

can't inject the dependency of sessionFactory, but everything seems to be correct :(
why don't you try to remove @autowired of session factory, put get/set an add property ref at context in hibernateUserDao, just for testing what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Somtimes what Spring actually trying to say is:

```
There are multiple bean definitions...
```

I had this problem:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'metadataGeneratorFilter' is defined
```

once where I had an xml file like this:

```
<security:custom-filter ref="metadataGeneratorFilter" before="CHANNEL_FILTER"/>

<beans:bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.  MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="metadataGenerator"/>
</beans:bean>
```