# Can not autowire interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I try to autowire a interface from my controller I get the exception below:
StackTrace:

```
Could not autowire field: com.projectShaun.service.AccountService com.projectShaun.controller.HomeController.accountService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.projectShaun.dao.AccountDao com.projectShaun.service.AccountServiceImpl.accountDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.projectShaun.dao.AccountDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
package com.projectShaun.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.projectShaun.service.AccountService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        modelAndView.addObject("greeting", "Welcome to projectShaun!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

And my application-context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd" >

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun.controller" />

  <tx:annotation-driven/>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectshaun" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
     <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.projectShaun.model.Account</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop 
         key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
  </bean>
</beans>
```

I am not sure why it is throwing this exception, I am not sure if it's something to do with the context: component scan base. I tried just putting `com.projectShaun` as the base package.

AccountDAO:

```
package com.projectShaun.dao;

import com.projectShaun.model.Account;

public interface AccountDao {

void persistAccount (Account account);
}
```

Comment: Your problem is in the DAO declared in the service. Set it as @Repository

Comment: Read the stack trace: Could not autowire field: private  com.projectShaun.dao.AccountDao 
->
Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory . No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911356/nosuchbeandefinitionexception-how-to-initialise-sessionfactory-bean

Comment: could you please add your AccountDao

Comment: Edited question, now contains accountDAO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says :

- you correctly (try to) autowire an `accountService` bean in you `HomeController` bean
- you correctly (try to) autowire an `AccountDAO` in `accountService`

but the error is in wiring `AccountDaoImpl.sessionFactory` because spring cannot find any `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` bean.

Comment: I think that framework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean doesn't implements org.hibernate.SessionFactory

Comment: @JosefProcházka : It does not, but it implements `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>`. So if you ask Spring to inject it, you actually get a `SessionFactory`. But I think you are right in asking code for `AccountDaoImpl` ...

Answer (score 0):

Only a spring managed object can `Autowire` another component/service/repository, SO `AccountDao` need to be anotated as a Spring bean with `@Named` or `@Component`.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is that Spring is not able to Created Beans due to missing dependency

> exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

clearly states that it doesn't have a bean configured for SessionFactory.
which is required by `AccountDaoImpl.sessionFactory` .